# Set home as screen that is not in tabs. Wix V2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I've been trying to learn react and I've been using the Wix Navigation.

I want the first screen the user lands on to be a screen that is not in the bottom tabs selection.

They will land on Screen0 and have the ability to navigate to Screen1 and Screen2 from the tabs.

So my question is, how do I set the landing screen to a be screen that isn't in the bottom tabs?

```
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      children: [
        {
          stack: {
            children: [{
              component: {
                name: "Screen1",
              },
            }],      
            options: {
              bottomTab: {
                text: 'Screen1',
                icon: require('../assets/icons/Screen1.png')
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          stack: {
            children: [{
              component: {
                name: "Screen2",
              },
            }],  
            options: {
              bottomTab: {
                text: 'Screen2',
                icon: require('../assets/icons/Screen2.png')
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```